# How to find the closest bounded rational approximation to a rational number?

Tags: approximation, rational-numbers, computational-mathematics

Say I have a rational number $a/b$ and I want to find its closest rational approximation $x/y$ where
$$x_- \leq x \leq x_+$$
$$y_- \leq y \leq y_+$$
for some constants $x_\pm$, $y_\pm$.
How can I compute the integers $x$ and $y$ efficiently, given the rest?

Comment: A standard tool for good approximations is the continued fraction expansion. But we would have to be lucky to land within the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following ***PDFs***:
http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-48-prev.pdf & 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ahnld1wtvqiurz/Continued%20fraction%20expansion.pdf?dl=0
This will clarify your issue.

Comment: I'm not finding a direct answer to the question in the PDF; however, so far Proposition 2.2 seems relevant, and I do see error bounds and such, so it seems like it might be possible to derive it easily, but if you already know the answer, I'd appreciate it if you could just paste it here, since it'd save everyone reading this a lot of time.